# Allow to check only one score out of four in a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have html table. There are four checkboxes on the same row with score from 1 to 4:

```
  <table class="quartz-table" id="perfskills_table">     
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Driver</th>
        <th>Sub-Driver</th>
        <th>Skill</th>  
        <th style="text-align: right;"><span style="margin-right: 60px;">Marks</span></th>  
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="full_qst" ng-repeat="perf_skill in perfList">
        <td>{{ perf_skill.driver }}</td>
        <td>{{ perf_skill.subdriver }}</td>
        <td>{{ perf_skill.skills }}</td>
        <td> 
          <div class="mrk">
            <img alt="" src="imagesQuartz/check.png" class="check">
            <label class="choice" for="{{perf_skill.id}}.1">
              <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" type="checkbox" id="{{perf_skill.id}}.1" 
                     ng-model="value1" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-click="updateForm(value1,perf_skill)"> 1 </label>
            <label class="choice" for="{{perf_skill.id}}.2">
              <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" id="{{perf_skill.id}}.2" type="checkbox" 
                     ng-model="value2" ng-true-value="2" ng-false-value="0" ng-click="updateForm(value2,perf_skill)"> 2 </label>
            <label class="choice" for="{{perf_skill.id}}.3">
              <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" id="{{perf_skill.id}}.3" type="checkbox"
                     ng-model="value3" ng-true-value="3" ng-false-value="0" ng-click="updateForm(value3,perf_skill)"> 3 </label>
            <label class="choice" for="{{perf_skill.id}}.4">
              <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" id="{{perf_skill.id}}.4" type="checkbox"
                     ng-model="value4" ng-true-value="4" ng-false-value="0" ng-click="updateForm(value4,perf_skill)"> 4 </label>
          </div>  
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I call my js script with this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  loadScript("Quartz/quartz/scoreboard/checkbox.js", function(){});  
</script>
```

And checkbox.js where I try to not allow user to check more than one checkbox in the row:

```
$('input.q').on('change', function() {
  $(this).parents('.full_qst').find(".q[name='"+$(this).attr("name")+"']").not(this).prop('checked',false);
  if ($(this).closest('tr').find('input:checked').length > 0) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.check').css('visibility', 'visible');
  } else {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.check').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  }
});
```

It has a weird behavior. Sometime it works sometimes it doesnt.

[image]
[image]

How can I restrict the system to allow user check only one checkbox and display hidden image after checkbox is checked? If another one is checked then change the value. I use angularjs. Maybe there is a way to do it in angular?

Comment: Checkbox is for multiple selects, radio button is for only one selection. This is a convention. If you are creating checkboxes but only one can be selected then it must be a radio button. You can't create checkboxes and write a complicated code to prevent a user from selecting multiple checkboxes. Go see [Input radio element](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/radio)

Comment: Juste change your checkboxes to radio buttons and that's it

Answer (score 1):

Checkbox is for multiple selects, radio button is for only one selection. This is a convention. If you are creating checkboxes but only one can be selected then it must be a radio button. You can't create checkboxes and write a complicated code to prevent a user from selecting multiple checkboxes. Go see [Radio button HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/radio)  and [Radio Buttons UX Design](https://uxplanet.org/radio-buttons-ux-design-588e5c0a50dc)

Just change your checkboxes into radio buttons.

```html
 <table class="quartz-table" id="perfskills_table">     
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Driver</th>
        <th>Sub-Driver</th>
        <th>Skill</th>  
        <th style="text-align: right;"><span style="margin-right: 60px;">Marks</span></th>  
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="full_qst" ng-repeat="perf_skill in perfList">
        <td>{{ perf_skill.driver }}</td>
        <td>{{ perf_skill.subdriver }}</td>
        <td>{{ perf_skill.skills }}</td>
        <td> 
          <div class="mrk">
            <img alt="" src="imagesQuartz/check.png" class="check">
            <label class="choice" for="{{perf_skill.id}}.1">
              <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" type="radio" id="{{perf_skill.id}}.1" 
                     ng-model="value1" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-click="updateForm(value1,perf_skill)"> 1 </label>
            <label class="choice" for="{{perf_skill.id}}.2">
              <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" id="{{perf_skill.id}}.2" type="radio" 
                     ng-model="value2" ng-true-value="2" ng-false-value="0" ng-click="updateForm(value2,perf_skill)"> 2 </label>
            <label class="choice" for="{{perf_skill.id}}.3">
              <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" id="{{perf_skill.id}}.3" type="radio"
                     ng-model="value3" ng-true-value="3" ng-false-value="0" ng-click="updateForm(value3,perf_skill)"> 3 </label>
            <label class="choice" for="{{perf_skill.id}}.4">
              <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" id="{{perf_skill.id}}.4" type="radio"
                     ng-model="value4" ng-true-value="4" ng-false-value="0" ng-click="updateForm(value4,perf_skill)"> 4 </label>
          </div>  
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: radio button will allow to choose only one option in the whole table. There are might up to 30 rows in html table. If I use radio button system allows me to choose only one radio button. But I need to be able to choose it on every row

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy Radio button works by same name. If same name then only one can be ticked. Juste put different names on the different rows

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="quartz-table" id="perfskills_table">     
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Driver</th>
        <th>Sub-Driver</th>
        <th>Skill</th>  
        <th style="text-align: right;"><span style="margin-right: 60px;">Marks</span></th>  
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="full_qst" ng-repeat="perf_skill in perfList">
        <td>{{ perf_skill.driver }}</td>
        <td>{{ perf_skill.subdriver }}</td>
        <td>{{ perf_skill.skills }}</td>
        <td> 
          <div class="mrk">
            <img alt="" src="imagesQuartz/check.png" class="check">
            <label class="choice" for="{{perf_skill.id}}.1">
              <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" type="radio" id="{{perf_skill.id}}.1" 
                     ng-model="value1" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-click="updateForm(value1,perf_skill)"> 1 </label>
            <label class="choice" for="{{perf_skill.id}}.2">
              <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" id="{{perf_skill.id}}.2" type="radio" 
                     ng-model="value2" ng-true-value="2" ng-false-value="0" ng-click="updateForm(value2,perf_skill)"> 2 </label>
            <label class="choice" for="{{perf_skill.id}}.3">
              <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" id="{{perf_skill.id}}.3" type="radio"
                     ng-model="value3" ng-true-value="3" ng-false-value="0" ng-click="updateForm(value3,perf_skill)"> 3 </label>
            <label class="choice" for="{{perf_skill.id}}.4">
              <input class="q" name="q1_a[]" id="{{perf_skill.id}}.4" type="radio"
                     ng-model="value4" ng-true-value="4" ng-false-value="0" ng-click="updateForm(value4,perf_skill)"> 4 </label>
          </div>  
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

change check boxes to radio buttons